# VLOOKUP Equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, vlookup, create-table

I have 2 tables: `operations` with client processing data and `customers` with age data. I want create new table, `vlookup` and add new column `Age` from `customers` to `operations`, but it doesnot work:

```
CREATE TABLE new_schema.total AS (
    SELECT new_schema.operations.Id_check,new_schema.operations.ID_client, new_schema.customers.Age 
    INNER JOIN Age ON new_schema.operations.ID_client=new_schema.customers.ID_client
);
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the Excel `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic syntax errors. There's no `FROM` clause to specify the first table, and `INNER JOIN` must be followed by the table you're joining with, not a column.

And you said you wanted the new table to be named `vlookup`, but you created `total` instead.

```
CREATE TABLE new_schema.vlookup AS (
    SELECT o.id_check, o.id_client, c.age
    FROM new_schema.operations AS o
    INNER JOIN new_schema.customers AS c ON o.id_client = c.id_client
);
```